# Memory consumpton inside sidekiq worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, background-process, sidekiq

1. Does loading multiple `Models` in sidekiq worker can cause memory leak? Does it get garbage collected?

For example:

```
class Worker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
    Model.find_each do |item|

    end
  end
end
```

2. Does using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` inside worker can cause problems? Or this connection automatically closes?

Comment: Worth a read (from author of Sidekiq)~: https://www.mikeperham.com/2015/10/14/optimizing-sidekiq/ .. also, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978396/sidekiq-not-deallocating-memory-after-workers-have-finished

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34462164/3011280

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running into a problem that I also had with a "worker" - the actual problem was the code, not Sidekiq in any way, shape or form.

In my problematic code, I thoughtlessly just loaded up a boatload of models with a big, fat, greedy query (hundreds of thousands of instances).

I fixed my worker/code quite simply. For my instance, I transitioned my DB call from `all` to use [find_in_batches](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_in_batches) with a lower number of objects pulled for the batch.

```
Model.find_in_batches(100) do |record| 
# ... I like find_in_batches better than find_each because you can use lower numbers for the batch size
# ... other programming stuff
```

As soon as I did this, a job that would bring down Sidekiq after a while (running out of memory on the box) has run with `find_in_batches` for 5 months without me even having to restart Sidekiq ... Ok, I may have restarted Sidekiq some in the last 5 months when I've deployed or done maintenance :), but not because of the worker!

Comment: The OP already uses `find_each` what does basically the same than `find_in_batches(1000) { |batch| batch.each ...`

Comment: Sorry, yes. I will edit my post ... I like find_in_batches better because you can control the batch size (versus find_each, which grabs a default 1000).